# Scala recursively overwrite column type in DF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to transform the year, month and day columns in my dataframe schema from Integer to string.

```
 |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- month: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- day: integer (nullable = true)
```

it should return the same DF with but column type changed to `String` for the specific columns.

The error i am getting is

[image]
This is my function:

```
def transformDate(df: Dataset[Row], spark: SparkSession): Dataset[Row] = {
    val cols = Seq("month","day","year")

    for (col <- cols) {
    val df  = df.withColumn(col, $"col".cast(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType))
}
    df
    }
```

What is wrong with my function?

Comment: Well, you want to mutate an immutable val, and that is not possible. - You can do this, `var df2 = df` as the first line of your function, and then use `df2` on your code. - A more functional solution would be `List("month","day","year").foldLeft(df){ (df, col) => df.withColumn(col, $"col".cast(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType)) }`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez you should just post that as an answer.